# How to suspend touchesBegan and only use touchesMoved vice versa?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

At the moment I am programming a game in swift, Xcode and I would like the user to be able to choose what controls they want (either slide or tap). As of now I have been able to make my SKNode slide in the main game scene, as well as respond to tapping. However I have found that the SKNode shakes constantly when you slide (as the touchesBegan function thinks I'm tapping on the screen).

If anyone knows the best way to suspend one of the functions while the other stays active please let me know :)

For example:
The user chooses to play the game by sliding, I would like to suspend the touchesBegan function but keep the touchesMoved active.

Comment: Isn't this why gesture recognizers exist? To be sure, SKNode is not a UIView so it can't have a gesture recognizer; but an SKView is and can.

Comment: Not sure I am following you here.  You can't have a touchesMoved if the touch never began.

Comment: What do you do in `touchesBegan`? Can you post your code? If the control method is gestures, it should be easy to not try and move the node via touches as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a delegate method to check if one gesture fails, if is true the other gesture is recognized. For example, in my project I have two gestures, tap once and tap twice and I used:

```
 public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if otherGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouches == 2 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

For more information check Apple's reference: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1620006-shouldrequirefailure

Comment: This doesn't check if it fails, this says a gesture cannot be recognized until the other gesture fails.  Like if you have a double tap and a single tap, you require double tap to fail in order for it to register as a single tap.